# Looking for an old animated show about humans in body armor

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, armor

As far as I remember it ran around the 90s, or perhaps very early 2000s. Not the Centurions. The show had somewhat futuristic theme, about humans wearing armor in gold and blue with glass visors. Remember the main protagonist was a blond man.

Comment: Why were they wearing armor? Who were they fighting?

Comment: What made it futuristic? Can you describe any more details?

Comment: Was it anime or western animation? Without details, this looks like "Fate stay night" but I need more details.

Comment: Not much to go on given how broad the description is. Look at Exo-squad, which ran from 93-95ish. Doesn't sound like the CGI Starship Troopers show. New Adventures of He-man ended in 1990. Eagle Riders is a possibility (1996) but seems unlikely. The Flash Gordon cartoon has a blonde protag but I'm not sure they wear armor.

Comment: Agreed. We need more details. There's a list of questions at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info that might prompt you for more details that you can add.